# Do USB memory sticks and memory cards not have S.M.A.R.T. data on-board?

Tags: usb, memory, ssd, usb-flash-drive, smart

As I understand it, USB memsticks (and memory cards) use the same basic technology as SSD disks.

But then why does CrystalDiskInfo detect and show all kinds of information for all my HDDs and SSDs, but not for my memory sticks and memory cards?

Is the answer that, for some reason, USB memsticks and flash memory cards do not have this "S.M.A.R.T." data? But if so, why not?

My trusty sticks are more than doing their very valuable duty in my household. I shall certainly like to know whether they are "going" or doing fine, just as I like to inspect my equally valuable HDDs/SSDs.

The program just never even detects my USB memsticks or memory cards when plugged in, but always detect each of my external USB HDDs and all my internal drives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, most SSDs and flash drives use the same basic *data storage* technology. However, the *control* technology are completely different. It is the controller which maintains and reports this S.M.A.R.T information.

S.M.A.R.T. was first introduced to predict failures of rotating hard disks and is a part of the ATA protocol. Consequently, access to it was implemented through some ATA command. SSDs implementing ATA inherited this support. But USB mass storage devices don't use ATA protocol, they use special adapted subset of SCSI protocol to actually interact with the storage. That subset doesn't contain this command. (Modern extensions of SCSI, implemented in Serial Attached SCSI a.k.a. SAS, *do* contain similar functionality, though it's largely different from S.M.A.R.T. and USB subset doesn't allow for it either.)

Some USB mass storage devices are implemented as ATA disks sitting behind SAT bridges (SAT stands for SCSI-ATA Translation). Some of those bridges support translating S.M.A.R.T., some not. If your portable storage is a standard SATA HDD or SSD in an USB-SATA enclosure, it might be possible to query parameters from it, but not always, it depends on the bridge used, and with `smartmontools` it sometimes require a command line parameter to tell it to go through the bridge, `-d sat`.

Memory cards use even another protocol, and different cards might use different protcols. Most common are SD cards which basically use SPI to communicate, which is low level protocol to communicate between different chips; in case of memory card, SPI is used to communicate with serial NAND flash chips. Think of it as a direct access to the memory cells. This is very low level, so it doesn't have such standard command, because there is no controller which could store and maintain performance statistics like S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: Just a small correction/addition: Most memory cards (SD, MMC, possibly others) do in fact have an intelligent storage controller. They definitely could accommodate some sort of SMART, but they don’t. Well, maybe SD Express does, dunno.

Comment: Even when you have intelligent controller, it still implements some SPI NAND access protocol [like this](https://www.endrich.com/fm/2/GD5F4GQ4UAYIG.pdf) towards the host, and I never have seen a specification of such a protocol that includes a command similar in functionality to SMART.

Comment: Also one must keep in mind hard drives were not considered removeable items when SMART was introduced.  Floppy drives (standard and Zip/Jaz) and optical reader/writers never had anything like SMART, and that is what NAND-based media such as SmartMedia, SecureDigital (SD), xD (Olympus), and Memory Stick (Sony) was superseding.  Initial capacities on these devices I believe were the next step up from floppy - 2MBytes.  USB mass storage devices soon followed.  Of course now you have 1TB SD cards :).

Comment: Don’t forget that most USB flash drives and SD cards are simply not built to last. Many die quite quickly. So a full set of S.M.A.R.T. data might indicate if/when a drive _might_ die from wear and tear. Or they might just die from mishandling. If you manufacture USB flash drives and SD cards and end users could see how quickly these cheap cards die, how would that affect warranty claims and such. Yes, that’s cynical but I believe the bulk of the NAND chips used for USB flash drives and SD cards are low quality on purpose. Disposable media at best. S.M.A.R.T would just make the obvious clearer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm not sure how much (if anything) this says, but while a memstick recently died on me which was only 1.7 years old, I also have two quite well used 9+ year old sticks working perfectly.

Comment: @Obenour True. So do I. Never had a USB flash drive die on me suddenly, but I have had SD cards die like that. I believe this mostly happens from wear and tear on the connectors and the fact that USB and SD card connectors are always exposed and at a risk for static discharge. Many times “dead” SD cards only have dead controllers. But good luck transplanting the storage to a new SD card unless you are really, really, really good at micro-component soldering. Thus my feeling the USB flash drives and SD cards have no S.M.A.R.T. due to the high risk of damage as well as wear. (1/2)

Comment: @Obenour Imagine if a manufacturer had to “make good” on every dead USB flash drive and SD card out there? A hard drive or an SSD stays in a case most of their life; not the same with a USB flash drive or an SD card. And how much effort would a manufacturer need to put into “cause of death” of an SD card shoved into a shirt pocket versus the NAND wearing out. At the end of the day, S.M.A.R.T on USB flash drives and SD cards might be technically possible but economically makes no sense for the manufacturer; better just sell the stuff as disposable storage. (2/2)

Comment: Seems at least some (high end) SD cards can report status: https://www.hdsentinel.com/how_to_monitor_sd_card_health_status.php